# Crossplatform local database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have inherited a piece of software(written in python) from a previous employee at the company I work at. The software can either be "installed"(dragged in to documents and then ran) or can be portable. They like the software but now they want to be able to use it on Mac's as well as PC's. Most of it is browser based so it should be fine.

However the database is Postgres portable. Is there anyway that Mac can run this postgres portable database? I am assuming that the contents of the data files will be similar it would just be the application that starts the engine that would be different.

If that doesn't work is there any alternatives? Clients wont allow the data to be online as that would be the best way.
another possible soltution maybe SQLLite but I am not sure what (if any) limitations are in using that.

Comment: Postgres isn't a "file based" DBMS where you can just copy a single file to another computer and use it there. It's a full blown server component - and you can't copy the files that make up the database between different operating systems.

Comment: There is a full directory that is copied and it seems to work, causes no issues, other than now when they want to be able to access the same data on a mac.
But yeah before this I had only seen it server based.

Comment: Does it uses docker? the only way it could work "portable" would be with containers.

Comment: @Dan So its a python flask webserver thats runs and opens google chrome portable and then points to the pg_ctl -D points to a folder called data within that.
I assume its [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresqlportable/)

Comment: @Kni9ht Well, if your using PostgreSQL Portable from that link, as it says in its [requirements](https://github.com/garethflowers/postgresql-portable), just works on Windows. If you want it to work anywhere you have to use containers, like Docker.